# c# mvc confirmation email

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I`m trying to get send confirmation email with link (code) inside for new registered users to confirm their email, this is a code im using, does anyone see whats wrong with it ? I use credentials from hosting, they are working normal on other methods.

```
public class Cls_SendMail
{
    public Cls_SendMail(string mailid, string message, string subject)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage objmail = new MailMessage();
            objmail.To.Add(mailid);
            objmail.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FROMEMAIL"].ToString());
            objmail.Subject = subject;
            string Body;
            Body = message;
            objmail.Body = Body;
            objmail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.Host = "mail.host.com";
            smtp.Port = 587; // 465; //Gmail works on this port
            smtp.Timeout = 100000;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FROMEMAIL"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FROMPWD"]);
            smtp.Send(objmail);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}


 var Token = (from p in context.webpages_Memberships where p.UserId == model.Id select p.ConfirmationToken).FirstOrDefault();
            var resetLink = "<a href='" + Url.Action("ConfirmAccount", "SignUp", new { un = model.Id, rt = Token }, "http") + "' style='color: #28BDF2;'>"+confirm+"</a>";

            string csspath = "http://localhost:50467/EmailHTML/stylesheets/email.css";
            string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string myString = "";
            UsersContext dbcontext = new UsersContext();
            var username = string.Empty;
            var user = dbcontext.UserProfiles.Find(model.Id);
            if (user!=null)
            {
                username = user.UserName;
            }
            myString = readFile;
            myString = myString.Replace("%{#{CssPath}#}%", csspath);
            myString = myString.Replace("%{#{Name}#}%", model.FirstName);
            myString = myString.Replace("%{#{UserName}#}%", username);
            myString = myString.Replace("%{#{ConfirmLink}#}%", resetLink);
            string subject = acountconfirm;
            string body = myString;
            try
            {
                //call for send mail
                Cls_SendMail mail = new Cls_SendMail(model.Email, body, subject);
                TempData["Message"] = Resource.mailhassent;
            }
            catch (Exception )
            {
                TempData["Message"] = Resource.Erroroccurredwhilesendingemail;
            }
```

Comment: Can you add the exception message you are getting?

Comment: And what is the problem? Does it send the mail or not? And why do you write an empty try/catch? How could you know if this code has errors if you suppress the exception message without any logging?

Comment: btw. it is never a good practise to leave the `Catch` block empty.

Comment: Ive added exception ex and i forgot to remove, originally is without it.

Comment: Email doesnt arrive, credentials are working.Debugger doesnt break ..

Comment: as suggestion, look to settings of your gmail account, you should have 2-factors authorization enabled. I remember that I have same problem along time ago

Comment: why do you need `Timeout` ? There are simple working example https://stackoverflow.com/a/32336/3917754

Comment: I dont use GMAIL, i use domain host, i use same parameters on other method and its working correctly, timout in case of hold? When i test it in debugger it pass normally ...

Comment: [Edit] your question to add the details from your comments here.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong, it couldbe your configuration or a spam filter or ...  You will have to (learn to) debug this yourself.

Comment: You may have to look into the smtp logs.

Comment: What configuration @HenkHolterman?

Comment: All of it. ____

Comment: @HenkHolterman i added more

Comment: Don't catch and swallow Exceptions like that, willing to bet that is your problem. Also, don't do an "action" in your class's constructor. Create a "Send" method. These things are a debugging nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

So after hours and hours of thinking, i`ve realized i haven`t setup credentials in web.config

Solution: Check webconfig.

Comment: You should delete the question if it was a simple oversight or typographical error.